# Adding Corine WMS to Shiny Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I'm trying to add Corine land cover data to a `shiny` `leaflet` map. However, I'm struggling to decipher the WMS XML data so that I can include the appropriate server URL and layer. The WMS information can be found [here](https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer) and [here](https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS).

I've included and MRE below of what I thought the correct details should be to display Corine 2018 landcover data but I just get a grey `leaflet` map.

If unable to provide a straight up solution to this question, can someone help me to interpret the XML data so that I can do this in future for other WMS providers?

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Map"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("map")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$map<-renderLeaflet({
       leaflet() %>% 
            addWMSTiles( "https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/WmsServer", layers = "1",
                         options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = T)) %>% 
            setView(lng = -1.8, lat = 52.0, zoom = 5)
        
        
    })
    
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

layer 1 is Guadeloupe. In the metadata XML:

```
<Layer queryable="1">
<Name>1</Name>
<Title>U2018_CLC2018_V2020_20u1_FR_GLP_R_WM</Title>
```

which then goes:

```
<westBoundLongitude>-61.906490</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>-60.904868</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>15.735481</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>16.607732</northBoundLatitude>
```

Layer 12 has main European coverage:

```
<Name>12</Name>
<Title>Corine Land Cover 2018 raster</Title>
...
<westBoundLongitude>-56.505142</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>72.906158</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>24.283655</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>72.664410</northBoundLatitude>
```

Its easier to test this without firing up a shiny server with plain leaflet:

```
url = "https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/WmsServer"
    leaflet() %>% 
        addWMSTiles( url, layers = "12",
                    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = T)) %>% 
        setView(lng = -1.8, lat = 52.0, zoom = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it threw me that layer 1 (in a European land cover map) would be covering Guadelope, of all places!

Comment: The layer names are *not* very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. The URL is correct but the layer name should have been "12" (not "1" as in my answer above). For those that may struggle to interpret these WMS XML files in future, I would recommend using QGIS (or similar) to get an easy-to-read list of WMS files e.g. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_wms.html